# Can't create ramdisks of different size with module brd. (Linux)

Tags: ramdisk

I'm creating ram block devices on a linux machine for a project we're working on.
I don't want to use tmpfs.

When I use module brd to create a ramdisk I run the command

modprobe brd rd_size=1048576

This creates 16 devices -> /dev/ram[0-15] (all of size 1 GB)

But now I want to create two ramdisks of different sizes, say 1Gb and 2Gb.

I also understand I might be able to use lvm to "merge" two devices together and create a new 2GB device from two 1GB devices.

But I want the module to create ramdisks of different sizes without having to do the merging.

I've looked around for a method to do this, but it just seems that there is no way.

Does anyone know if there is a way to do this?

Comment: **Why** don't you want to use tmpfs? Tmpfs solves your problem.

Comment: If I want to format it with a different filesystem like ext3 or something. I want a block device.

Comment: NFS won't export tmpfs

Answer (score 1):

I'd been looking for similar information on RAM disks (in my case, planned RAM disk as part of RAID 1 array).  For a partial answer, as I'm not sure how to create RAM disks of differing sizes:

Try: modprobe brd rd_nr=1 rd_size=1048576 max_part=0

Which should create one, 1GB RAM disk.  Perhaps tailor rd_nr=1 to rd_nr=3?  That should give three 1G RAM disks, leaving assembling them to 2GB perhaps to LVM?

Referenced solution, and pardon the necro-post answer (there remains very lacking documentation on this subject):  http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=114458

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1**

Create a 4GB ram disk.  Then create two partitions on it.  The first partition would be 1GB, the second partition would be 2GB.  Use the partitons.

Here is the modprobe command:

```
modprobe  brd  rd_nr=1  rd_size=4194304  max_part=2
```

I assume you already know (or can easily learn) how to partition a device, for example with `gdisk`.  We need a device that is larger than 3GB because the MBR or GPT header will use a small amount of space on the device.

**Option 2**

Create two 2GB ram disks.  Then create a 1GB partition on one of them.  Use the 2GB ram disk and the 1GB ram partition.

```
modprobe  brd  rd_nr=2  rd_size=2097152  max_part=1
```

**Note:**  I believe memory on `brd` devices is only allocated when written to.  So the neither of the above options wastes memory.